# How do you specify a variable to be binary in SAS?

Tags: sas

Suppose we have the following:

```
 proc optmodel;
     var  x{1..3} <= 1 integer;
```

I want the variables to be 0 and 1 only. How do I specify this in the above statement?

Answer (score 1):

Think that you can specify straightforward like:

```
proc optmodel;
 var  x{1..3} binary;
```